# Забрать данные из JSON файла при помощи Observable. Angular 2/5

Tags: json, angular2, angular5

Тема широко освещена в интернете, на *stackoverflow.com* нашёл более 4-х вопросов по этой теме. Но решения, приведённые там, почему-то не работают. При этом данные из файла вполне получается забрать промисом. Адрес файла в переменной `apiHost` задан верно. По крайней мере, промис данные оттуда забирает нормально.

**`friends.service.ts`**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Friend } from './friend';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class FriendsService {

  public apiHost: string = './assets/generated.json';

  constructor(private http: Http, private messageService: MessageService) {

  }

  getFriends():Observable<any> {

    return this.http.get(this.apiHost)
            .map((res:Response) => {res.json();})
            .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Can\'t get generated.json'));

  }

  getFriend(id: string):Observable<any> {

    /* ... */

  }
}
```

**`friends-list.component.ts`**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Friend } from '../friend';
import { FriendsService } from '../friends.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-friends-list',
  templateUrl: './friends-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./friends-list.component.css']
})

export class FriendsListComponent implements OnInit {

  public friends: Object;

  selectedFriend: Friend;

  onSelect(friend: Friend): void {
    this.selectedFriend = friend;
  }

  getFriends(): void {
    this.friendsService.getFriends().subscribe(result => this.friends = result);
  }

  constructor(private friendsService: FriendsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getFriends();
  }

}
```

Ошибок нет ни в консоли, ни в браузере. **Что не так? Почему сервис не возвращает данные файла?**

Для примера, рабочий код с промисом:

**`friends.service.ts`**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Friend } from './friend';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http'; 
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';  // Чтобы забрать инфу промисом
import { MessageService } from './message.service';

@Injectable()
export class FriendsService {

  public apiHost: string = './assets/generated.json';

  constructor(private http: Http, private messageService: MessageService) {

  }

  // Забираем json промисом
  public getFriends(): Promise<Object> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiHost)
      .toPromise()
      .then((response) => {
        this.messageService.add({message: 'Список друзей загружен.', type: 'success'});
        return response.json();
      }).catch((err) => {
        this.messageService.add({message: 'Не удалось загрузить список друзей.', type: 'error'});
        console.log(err);
      });
  }


}
```

**`friends-list.component.ts`**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Friend } from '../friend';
import { FriendsService } from '../friends.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-friends-list',
  templateUrl: './friends-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./friends-list.component.css']
})

export class FriendsListComponent implements OnInit {

  public friends: Object;

  selectedFriend: Friend;

  onSelect(friend: Friend): void {
    this.selectedFriend = friend;
  }

  getFriends(): void {
    this.friendsService.getFriends().then(result => this.friends = result);
  }

  constructor(private friendsService: FriendsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getFriends();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий код для *Observable* такой:

**`friends.service.ts`**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Friend } from './friend';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class FriendsService {

    public apiHost: string = './assets/generated.json';

    constructor(private http: Http, private messageService: MessageService) {
        this.getFriends().subscribe();
    }

    getFriends():Observable<Array> {

        return this.http.get(this.apiHost);

    }

}
```

**`friends-list.component.ts`**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Friend } from '../friend';
import { FriendsService } from '../friends.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-friends-list',
  templateUrl: './friends-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./friends-list.component.css']
})

export class FriendsListComponent implements OnInit {

    public friends: Object;

    selectedFriend: Friend;

    onSelect(friend: Friend): void {
        this.selectedFriend = friend;
    }

    getFriends(): void {
        this.friendsService.getFriends().subscribe(result => {this.friends = result.json();});
    }

    constructor(private friendsService: FriendsService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getFriends();
    }

}
```